# Use jQuery/AJAX to get list of loggedin users from MySQL DB?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a site with a div that I want to list all currently logged in users. I set a bool in my DB where 1 means that users is logged in. I'm trying to dynamically generate the list using a jQuery AJAX call to a php page that polls the DB for all the logged in users.

The PHP code checks the DB and creates a list of all logged in users. My issue is I can't seem to get the jQuery function to load the data from the page.

```
<?php
   include ('settings.php');
   if ($db_found)
   {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE logged_in='1'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
      $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
      // Check if the account is already in the DB
      $i = 0;
      while ($i < $count)
      {
         $online = mysql_result($result,$i,"logged_in");
         if ($online == 1)
         {
            $user = mysql_result($result,$i,"displayname");
            print "<li>$user</li>";
         }
         $i++;
      }
      mysql_close($db_handle);
   }
?>
```

Whats wrong with the way I used the jQuery load so the loggedin.php page content would be displayed in the #loggedin-players div?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatePlayerList()
    {
    $('#loggedin-players').load('loggedin.php');
    }
    $setInterval("updatePlayerList()", 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be a `$` before `setInterval`

```
setInterval("updatePlayerList()", 5000);
```

Your function is never called.

Comment: Wow got to love typos. Thanks that was it, it was driving me nuts because this was such a simple thing to do.